# Что означает :> в строке форматирования {a:>30}?

Tags: python

```
print(f"Товар:{a:>30}")
```

Comment: это спецификация форматирования поля. `>` является операцией выравнивания, в данном случае `30` - ширина поля, то есть значение переменной `a` будет выровнено по правому краю поля занимая в нём 30 символов

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: а почему бы не поискать ответ самому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной строке кода конструкция `:>30` называется **спецификацией форматирования поля**, где `>` является опцией выравнивания поля, которая указывает, что значение должно быть выровнено по правому краю поля. В данном случае, число `30` указывает ширину поля, то есть значение переменной `a` будет выровнено по правому краю поля, занимая в нем `30` символов.

На примере выглядит так

```
a = "яблоко"
print(f"Товар:{a:>30}")
a = "яяяяблоко"
print(f"Товар:{a:>30}")
a = "яяяяяяяяяяблоко"
print(f"Товар:{a:>30}")
```

Вывод в терминале:

```
Товар:                        яблоко
Товар:                     яяяяблоко
Товар:               яяяяяяяяяяблоко
```

P.S. Если выйти за пределы 30 символов, то форматирование перестанет работать

```
a = "яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяблоко"
print(f"Товар:{a:>30}")
```

Вывод на терминале:

```
Товар:яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяблоко
```

Answer (score 1):

Выравнивание по правому краю с шириной 30

Тест

```
a = "bread"
print(f"Товар:{a:>30}")
```

Результат:

```
Товар:                         bread
```

Comment: 20 или 30??????

Comment: @Acinit спасибо, поправил